# Is it possible to update Lucene document field from custom token filter?

Tags: lucene

This is what I want to do.

1. I have some calculation for each token/term/word in the document.
2. After calculating each token/term/word, I would like to sum (for example) this number (described in #1) and store it as an attribute of the document.

As I understand, for #1, I can use custom token filter which will help me to perform calculation on each word. After all the words in a document are processed, I will sum up those number for a given document.

My question is, How can I save this aggregate number I calculated?  I would like to save it as an attribute or field of a document. As I understand, I can not access field in token filter. Is there any other strategy to achieve it?

Please guide.